# Alternative to Run a Robo test for Android compose applications during Google Play Console pre launch report

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, google-play-console

My organisation is migrating to building all Android UIs employing Jetpack Compose.

one of the blockers we envisage is that we can no longer Direct pre-launch report to test specific parts of our new apps by uploading a Robo script, recorded in Android Studio.

As we now see this pop up when we attempt to record a new script in Android Studio

[image: android studio screen shot]

I cannot find any information on when compose will be supported

or indeed on alternative approaches that will allow us to have google pre launch
reports to sign into our apps and complete a meaningful pre launch test

what are my options? (apart from be patient)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot register a Robo script for a Compose project in Android Studio, due to the limitations of the underlying framework.

We can create it manually following the Robo scripts reference guide : https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-scripts-reference

Comment: What does this mean in practice? Do you have an example? One of the key parts of that reference is a `resourceId` but there are no resource ids in a Compose layout.